# Add a Button to GoogleMap in Android

Tags: android

Hello guys This my Xml code

I use Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_restaurant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="new mark" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/remove_restaurant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_restaurant"
    android:text="clear mark" />
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/check_map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/remove_restaurant"
    android:text="just check" />
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It can show correctly just like the following image

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnbQ.png)

But when I opened the APP with my mobile, it just crashed

How can I solve it?

Error Message from Android Studio

```
10-15 20:43:30.100 20922-20922/com.ncku.addmarker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL     
EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: 
com.ncku.addmarker, PID: 20922

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    
ComponentInfo{com.ncku.addmarker/com.ncku.addmarker.MapsActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void    
  com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

   atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

at com.ncku.addmarker.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:24)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)                                                                         
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)                                                                        
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                        
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run     
(ZygoteInit.java:797)                                                                       
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Hi, can you paste here you log cat error..

Comment: It just said the program stop working ...

Or you mean the message from android studio?

Comment: Yes please post the log from android studio

Comment: I've changed my question

Comment: You just need to implement on MapReadyCallback or getMapASync

Answer (score 0):

For UI, you need to change your code...

If you want to add button on map fragment, then you need to add frame layout. As frame layout give an option to add the component on to the other component as a layer.

For crash, please provide crash logs.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this error showing because you have to not Generate a API key on google console. If you have try to load a map then you have must to Generate a API key.Try to this link and do step by step..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Comment: I am sure I have a API key because it is ok when I run the googlemap example